# How to define SharedPreferences from an Object?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm using shared_preferences.dart package. When the user login in the App, I load some preferences from an object of Settings named `Configuracion` that looks like attached.

The way I'm loading `_prefs` is as follows...

```
    final _prefs            = new PreferenciasUsuario();
    ConfiguracionModel _configuracion = new ConfiguracionModel();
    _configuracion          = await configuracionBloc.cargarConfiguracion(_prefs.idEmpresa);
    _prefs.idioma           = _configuracion.idioma;
    _prefs.medidaDistancia  = _configuracion.medidaDistancia;
    _prefs.medidaOxigeno    = _configuracion.medidaOxigeno;
    _prefs.medidaPeso       = _configuracion.medidaPeso;
    _prefs.medidaPesoUnidad = _configuracion.medidaPesoUnidad;
    _prefs.medidaTemp       = _configuracion.medidaTemp;

    //......a large list of more and more ....
```

Is there a way to reduce the large amount of code?

Something like `_prefs... = _configuracion...`

[image: Object Model]

Comment: use for each statement

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `sharedpreferences`. You need to save that data in a local database such as sembast, hive, or sqflite.

Comment: I’m getting ‘configuracion’ from Firebase. What I need is to define some _prefs from configuracion. My code is working fine, but I’m using a lot of code.

Comment: I can help you if you could tell me the types of both the prefs and configuration variable. And if it they are a custom class object then post the code for those classes as well.